# I Cannot Embed My Header File to Main.cpp

Tags: c++

I have a homework which is done with C++. I coded it using a Main.cpp and a header file (datastruct.h). Homework was done, compiled and run successfully; but submission rules allow me to use just one main.cpp. When I tried to include my code in header to main.cpp I get:

```
[main] C:\cygnus\cygwin-b20\H-i586-cygwin32\bin\g++.exe 1000 (0) handle_exceptions: Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION
[main] g++ 1000 (0) handle_exceptions: Dumping stack trace to g++.exe.core
```

Note that: **My question is not just about this error, it is about I get this error only I embed my header code to main.cpp.** When they are separated, it works fine. 
Here is my main.cpp when header codes were not included:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "datastruct.h"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
  Game myGame;
  myGame.initializer(argv[1]);
  cout << myGame.gamePlay();
  myGame.cleaner();

  return 0;
}
```

And here is "datastruct.h":

```
#ifndef DATASTRUCT_H
#define DATASTRUCT_H

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int abs(int k) {
  if(k < 0) k = -k;
  return k;
}

struct Card {
  int value;
  Card* prev;
};

struct Deck {
  Card* top ;
  int cardNum;
  void addCard(int xd);
  int dropCard();
  void create();
  void clear();
  void print();
};

void Deck::clear(/* arguments */) {
  Card *p;
  while(top)
  {
    p = top;
    top = top -> prev;
    delete p;
  }
}

int Deck::dropCard(/* arguments */) {
  Card* cardPtr;
  int returnVal = top -> value;
  cardPtr = top;
  top = top -> prev;
  delete cardPtr;
  cardNum--;
  return returnVal;
}

void Deck::create() {
  cardNum = 0;
  top = NULL;
}

void Deck::addCard(int xd) {
  Card* newCard;
  newCard = new struct Card;
  newCard -> value = xd;
  newCard -> prev = top;
  top = newCard;
  cardNum++;
}

struct Game {
  Deck* p1;
  Deck* p2;
  Deck* table;
  Deck* bin;
  void initializer(char* filename);
  void cleaner();
  void gamePrint();
  void p1gives();
  void p2gives();
  int gamePlay();
};

int Game::gamePlay()
{
  int cardTaken;

  while (true)
  {
    if((p1->cardNum ==0) || (p2->cardNum ==0) || (table->cardNum ==0)) break;

    cardTaken = table->dropCard();
    if (cardTaken < 0) {
      for (int i = 0; i < abs(cardTaken); i++) {
        if(p1->top == NULL) break;
        p1gives();
      }
    } else {
      for (int i = 0; i < cardTaken; i++) {
        if(p2->top == NULL) break;
        p2gives();
      }
    }

    if((p1->cardNum ==0) || (p2->cardNum ==0) || (table->cardNum ==0)) break;

    cardTaken = table->dropCard();
    if (cardTaken < 0) {
      for (int i = 0; i < abs(cardTaken); i++) {
        if((p1->top == NULL) || (p2->top == NULL)) break;
        p2gives();
      }
    } else {
      for (int i = 0; i < cardTaken; i++) {
        if((p1->top == NULL) || (p2->top == NULL)) break;
        p1gives();
      }
    }
  }
  return (bin -> cardNum);
}

void Game::p1gives()
{
  if(p2 -> top == NULL)
    p2 -> addCard(p1 -> dropCard());
  else if (p1 -> top -> value > p2 -> top -> value)
    p2 -> addCard(p1 -> dropCard());
  else if (p1 -> top -> value <= p2 -> top -> value)
    bin -> addCard(p1 -> dropCard());
}

void Game::p2gives()
{
  if (p1 -> top == NULL)
    p1 -> addCard(p2 -> dropCard());
  else if(p2 -> top -> value > p1 -> top -> value)
    p1 -> addCard(p2 -> dropCard());
  else if(p2 -> top -> value <= p1 -> top -> value)
    bin -> addCard(p2 -> dropCard());
}

void Game::cleaner()
{
  p1 -> clear();
  p2 -> clear();
  table -> clear();
  bin -> clear();

  delete p1;
  delete p2;
  delete table;
  delete bin;
}

void Game::initializer(char* filename)
{
  ifstream myFile(filename);
  int tableDeckCount, playerDeckCount;
  myFile >> tableDeckCount;
  myFile >> playerDeckCount;

  p1 = new struct Deck;
  p1 -> create();
  p2 = new struct Deck;
  p2 -> create();
  table = new struct Deck;
  table -> create();
  bin = new struct Deck;
  bin -> create();

  for (int i = 0; i < tableDeckCount; i++) {
    int x;
    myFile >> x;
    table -> addCard(x);
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < playerDeckCount; i++) {
    int x;
    myFile >> x;
    p1 -> addCard(x);
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < playerDeckCount; i++) {
    int x;
    myFile >> x;
    p2 -> addCard(x);
  }
}

void Deck::print(/* arguments */) {
  Card* traverse;
  traverse = top;
  while (traverse) {
    cout << traverse -> value << " , " ;
    traverse = traverse -> prev;
  }
  cout << endl;
}

void Game::gamePrint()
{
  cout << "P1:" << endl;
  p1 -> print();
  cout << "P2:" << endl;
  p2 -> print();
  cout << "TABLE:" << endl;
  table -> print();
  cout << "BIN:" << endl;
  bin -> print();
}
#endif
```

I need to include header into main.cpp but when I copy codes I get error. Can someone help me?

Expected work example:

```
>g++ -std=c++0x -Wall -Wextra -Werror main.cpp -o cardgame 
>./cardgame example.game 
1
```

example.game file:

```
1 3
-2
6
7
8
1
5
4
```

Comment: Maybe you're supposed to only have a *single* file, where you put everything from the header file literally inside the `main.cpp` source file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ STATUS\_ACCESS\_VIOLATION error when program runs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9796200/c-status-access-violation-error-when-program-runs)

Comment: why not debug "g++.exe.core" this core file present?!

Comment: Cygwin B20 is twenty years old. I'm surprised it works at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the compilation in elevated privileges on Windows? (right-click run as administrator) /edit. Right-click on sh.exe for cygwin and go to compatibility and check the box "run as administrator")

also, for reference to those who negatively voted: https://developer.qualcomm.com/forum/qdn-forums/mobile-technologies/multimedia-optimization-hexagon-sdk/toolsinstallation/27100

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. But can you explain or give me link about why I need to use administrator mode?

Comment: Great it worked! I'm glad. The link should contain a short description, but basically it is windows UAC stopping the correct execution trying to protect your file system from potential virusses that can modify it. I'm not AS technically capable of explaining it though, sorry :)

remember to mark as the answer if you're happy!